# How to create project and item templates?

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I want to know how to create project and item templates in VS2008.
Can anybody explain to me step-by-step how to do that? I am new to templates.

Answer (score 2):

You need to study this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/bb980955.aspx